# React-native-blob-util couldn't find ANDROID_SDK_ROOT

Tags: android, react-native

`npx react-native run-android` causes the following error with module `react-native-blob-util` on Big Sur/React Native 0.66.1/Android Studio 2020.3.1:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/Users/macair/Documents/code/js/xyz_app5/node_modules/react-native-blob-util/android/build.gradle' line: 69

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-blob-util'.
> SDK location not found. Define location with an ANDROID_SDK_ROOT environment variable or by setting the sdk.dir path in your project's local properties file at '/Users/macair/Documents/code/js/xyz_app5/android/local.properties'.
```

The line of code in `react-native-blob-util 0.13.16` `build.gradle` which causes error is:

```
classpath += project.files(android.getBootClasspath().join(File.pathSeparator))
```

But a `.bash_profile` has been created with ANDROID_SDK_ROOT defined. Also in `project structure` under android studio `SDK` has been defined and pointing to `/Library/android/sdk`. What is really missing here?

Here is the SDK defined in `project structure`:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After installing Android 10 by following [setup](https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup) for Android in React Native, the error disappeared.